# Compressed matrix multiplication

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

When multiplying matrices in some real fields(like I have now) these matrices contains a lot of systimaticaly repeated values. The repeated values are not only zero so we can't call it sparse(?) 
For example lets take this matrix (In my case dimensions are 1000 x 1000):

```
0.8    0.8   0.8    0.1   0.1
0.8    0.8   0.8    0.7   0.7 
0.8    0.8   0.8    0.7   0.7
0.9    0.6   0.5    0.7   0.7
```

Then we are multiplying this matrix by a value matrix and got a result. For example, we are multiplying just by a vector V {v1, v2, v3, v4}. We can do normal matmul, but this is wasteful. We can compress the matrix:

```
 A1 = 0.8 * (v1 + v2 + v3)
 A2 = 0.7 * (v2 + v3 + v4)
```

And add this values again and again to the columns dot products.
If there is a lot of repetition amount of computation can be reduced in several times.
But effective implementation  looks hard to me. Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

You could decompose your matrix into a sum of sparse matrices.

```
0.8 0.8 0.8 0.1 0.1         1 1 1 0 0         0 0 0 0 0   0   0   0   0.1 0.1
0.8 0.8 0.8 0.7 0.7 = 0.8 * 1 1 1 0 0 + 0.7 * 0 0 0 1 1 + 0   0   0   0   0
0.8 0.8 0.8 0.7 0.7         1 1 1 0 0         0 0 0 1 1   0   0   0   0   0
0.9 0.6 0.5 0.7 0.7         0 0 0 0 0         0 0 0 1 1   0.9 0.6 0.5 0   0
```

Then your multiplication becomes a series of relatively simple to optimise multiplications and one big addition at the end.

Comment: In fact we can decompose to several dense matrix that are faster + map of sparse sums or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Split them into block matrices and modify the multiplying vector as such. You'll probably need a data structure to keep track for recombination.